# Boost search results by field value

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search, boosting

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, Is it possible to boost the search results by a  specific field value? What I see in SXA boosting rules that you adjust boost by adding a value statically, I want it to be dynamic based on a field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of them are static. Take a look at the whole list of supported boosting rules, in the end, you will find some SXA rules:

[image]

They are not dynamic as they are e.g.: comparing the field to the page field.

The other thing is that you can write your own rule is none of the existing suits your requirements. Check how SXA rules are written. There is an SXA specific pipeline called `resolveBoostingQuery` where you can add your custom rules. Take a look at how `ResolveFieldContainsCurrentPageFieldRule` or `ResolveFieldAndQueryMatchRule` are implemented.

Comment: I'm talking about the adjusting boost value, at the right at the Indexing & Search section, I want this value to be set to a field name where it get the value from this field in an OOB way

Comment: @MohamedYaseen I think you don't fully understand how boosting works. Those rules are building a predicate. Base on that predicate search engine is returning you some results. Some of those results are boosted as they match predicate exactly. You can't boost them base on the value from field of the item which will be found as you don't have those items at the time of preparing the predicate.